# Сортировка масива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть масив товаров такого вида, в нем есть категория и атрибуты, как можно перебрать масив по одинкаовым категориям(заранее не известно каким и сколько будет у нас товаров) и сравнить их атрибуты. Если название такие уже существуют - то ничего, а если нет - то необходимо добавить но с пустым значением

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "58"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "2222"
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
        }
    }
  [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "58"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => "100"
        }
    }
  [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "10"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "100"
        }
    }
}
```

Должно получиться такое

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "58"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(6) {
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "2222"
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => ""
        }
    }
  [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "58"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => ""
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => ""
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
        }
    }
  [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["category"] => "10"
      ["attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "100"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: какие-то наработки то у вас есть? покажите, что не получается.

Comment: в массиве не может быть одноименных ключей.

Comment: @Эдуард а где вы увидели одинаковые ключи?

Comment: @Manitikyl  `attributes_4_ru-ru` в конце массива. Ну и не только в конце.

Comment: @Эдуард понуал, вижу

Comment: @Эдуард это как пример, исправил, если так будеть проще подсказать куда двигаться

Comment: двигайтесь в сторону того, чтобы сначала и извлечь набор параметров для каждой категории, и записать их в массив, например, где id категории будет ключом.

Comment: потом проходите по исходному массиву, и сливайте полный набор пустых ключей и текущими параметрами